# How to show a Drupal Commerce coupon system on the cart page?

Tags: commerce

I am new in Drupal and working over a shopping site using [Drupal Commerce](https://drupal.org/project/commerce). My client's requirement is that to show a coupon field in the cart page through which user can add a coupon code. I have installed the [Commerce Coupon](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_coupon) module, but did not understand how to show the coupon form on the cart page.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_cp - Commerce Cart Pane module allows to add Coupon form on cart page.

Answer (score 0):

Basic rule of thumb using any module in Drupal is first read Documentation or Readme or Install files inside Drupal module.. That will tell you how the module works... Go through Project page for full details

- For fixed amount discount use [Commerce coupon fixed amount](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_coupon_fixed_amount)

For Example - Readme file explains how to create %off coupon

### Example - Create a '10% off' coupon

1) Install modules

Install:
   - Commerce Coupon
   - Commerce Coupon UI
   - Commerce coupon percentage

2) Create a 'Percentage coupon' coupon

Go to: Home > Administration > Store > Coupons

Click 'Create Coupon'

Choose 'Create Percentage coupon'
   (if you have no other coupon types clicking 'Create Coupon' will redirect to
    the 'Create Percentage coupon' form)

Create a percentage coupon with the following:

- Coupon Code: 10%OFF
- Number of Uses: 1 (change as necessary)
- Percentage Amount: 10
- Active: Yes

  Save

3) Enable the 'Coupons' area on one of your Commerce checkout panes

Go to: Home > Administration > Store > Configuration > Checkout settings

Move the 'Coupons' item into one of the checkout panes

Save

4) Test it!

Please do some basic research before posting questions like above .. Otherwise they will be put onhold :-)

Comment: I know this , you have mentioned above . But I need to show the coupon form in the cart page not any other page . Also I have view for the cart page an when I open that view and try to add coupon form at the footer of that view the coupon form is not appearing for selection.That's why I have asked this question . Still thanks for your quick response .

Comment: Already there exist an issue in the module issue queue.. Please find link here https://drupal.org/node/1684892